# Bring your own database?

Tags: directus

The website of Directus 7 states something along the lines „... bring your own database“. Now, I indeed do have a relational DB (consisting of a few related tables). Is it indeed possible to use Directus to use this DB together with Directus (without recreating the entire structure in a new Directus collection and then importing the data)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can install Directus on an existing database and it will pull in your tables (called collections), columns (called fields), and records (called items).

Comment: Ok, (finally) got it. Tried it with a simple example, worked nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Did anything change in more recent versions of Directus such that this no longer works? I'm using 9.21.2, connecting to an existing DB, see that it populated the directus schema with its system tables, but it doesn't show any of my other schema or tables. I've poked around all UI buttons, and can confirm the DB user has permissions to see the other schema/tables.

Comment: Tables are hidden in Settings/Data Model. There you can get them and after that, they are available in the Collection tab.